# date time picker bootstrap default date not displayed when revisited

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using date time picker extension to display calender for selecting delivery date. I am initializing it, and setting a default value like this:

```
var a = moment().add(1,'days');
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
format: 'DD/MM/YY',
minDate:a,
defaultDate:a
});
```

This disaplys default date of next day correctly, and user is able to fill the form and submit. But i give an option to modify the form before final confirmation. So, when user revisits the page for modification, i use the following code to display the form values from my database:

```
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" name = "delivery_date" 
        <?php if ($visited == 1) echo 'value = "'.$userdetails['deliverydate'].'"';?>>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
         </div>
```

The code works fine, when user selects any date other than the default date. When user selects the default date of next day, it is not displayed when the page is visited again. However, My database is updated with the default date, but its not displayed.

Please help me out.

Comment: *side note:* to keep the code tidy,  do not mix single quotes with double quotes

Comment: @Raptor I dont get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Take your `<input>` tag as example: You should use double quotes like this: `<input type="text" class="form-control" />`, instead of mixing with single quotes.